# Why do is there a gaping hole in camera view but not in viewport shading?

Tags: rendering, objects, 3d-view, camera, bevel

viewport:

[image: viewport]

camera view:

[image]
[image]
The shape is just a plane with two edges raised up to form a semi-room. Beveled the corners. Classic. I added a solidify modifier to see if being thicker would fix the hole but it didn't. The hole happens in rendering too.

shape of the background without object:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your clipping distance is too high. Select your camera, press the little camera icon in the bottom right of your screen. Then, reduce *Clip start* to the lowest value. Right now it is too high in the picture, make it lower than that

[image]